# c# HttpClient Прокси с авторизацией не работают

Tags: c#, proxy, httpclient

Пытаюсь отправить запрос используя прокси с авторизацией, делаю вот так:

```
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy),
            
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password"),

        }; 

        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            html = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;  

        }
```

Получаю исключение:

> WebException: Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (407) Требуется аутентификация посредника.

Без авторизации прокси работают. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не туда креды втыкаете `Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy) { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password") }`

Comment: И не используйте `.Result`, используйте `await` - `html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);` [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).